# Angular ngRepeat: dupes error (although there are no duplicate keys)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning MEAN, and have encountered an Angular error. I am trying to display form data in a table, however the data isn't going through and the error I receive is:

> angular.js:11500 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=topic%20in%20topics%20%20%7C%20filter%3A%20filter_q&p1=string%3Ap&p2=p
>       at Error (native)
>       at

In the index.html file I have:

```
discussion_board.controller('dashboardController', function($scope, usersFactory, topicsFactory){
      $scope.topics = [];
      $scope.users = [];

      topicsFactory.index(function(data){
        $scope.topics = data;
      })

      usersFactory.index(function(data){
        $scope.topics = data;
      })

      $scope.addtopic = function(){
        console.log("from controller)");
        topicsFactory.addTopic($scope.new_topic, function(topics){
          $scope.topics = topics;
          $scope.new_topic = {};
         });
      }
    })
discussion_board.factory('topicsFactory', function($http){
    var factory = {};
    var users = [];

    factory.index = function(callback) {
      $http.get('/topics').success(function(output){
        callback();
      });
    }

    factory.addTopic = function(info, callback) {
      console.log("from factory");
      $http.post('/topics', info).success(function(output){
        callback();
      });
    }
```

And in the view file:

```
<div ng-controller="dashboardController">
<h2>Welcome {{username}} !</h2>
<h5>Search:
    <input type="text" ng-model="filter_q" placeholder="search">
</h5>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Topic</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Posts</th>      
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="topic in topics  | filter: filter_q">
        <td>{{topic.category}}</td>
        <td>{{topic.name}}</td>
        <td>{{topic.username}}</td>
        <td>{{topic.posts}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I have added track by $index in the ng-repeat. When added before the filter, it adds a bunch of empty rows to the table. When inserted after the filter, there is no change.

Comment: Not sure if this is related to the issue, but I think you want to change  the call to usersFactory.index to assign the results to $scope.users rather than $scope.data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a race condition between your two service calls. Whichever finishes last is going to assign its results to $scope.topics. I assume that the call to the user service should look like this:

```
 usersFactory.index(function(data){
    $scope.users= data;
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

The errror `[ngRepeat:dupes]` is recieved when as the name suggest there are repeated index values.

I recommend you to debug your data recieved in the $http.post with a simple `console.log(output);` Remember that serialize your ng-repeat arrays is a good practice to prevent dupes errors.

That will solve the empty rows too

If you think that your responses are correctly formed try to paste a debug of what exactly you are recieving

Answer (score 0):

`track by $index` should be added after all other expressions in the `ngRepeat`. From [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> Note: track by must always be the last expression

I would suspect you see empty rows when your track by expression is added last (not the other way round as pointed out in your question). This most likely means you have empty or undefined objects in your `topics` array.

I would advise you to inspect the data you are receiving back from your factory methods.